# charge distribution on three conducting plates

Tags: capacitance

There are three parallel plates identical and equidistant. A charge q is given to the first plate.And then the second and third plate are connected with wire.Then how to find its charge distribution. My method was that first I assumed the charge on first plate to be q . Then I used when two conductors are joined by wire their potential becomes equal. Any body can explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all three conducting plates initially have zero net charge.

When a charge of $+Q$ is given to the first plate, it will result in an electric field between it and the other two plates.

[image]

When the second and third plate are connected with a conductor, they will be brought to equal potential, thereby allowing positive charges to move from plate 2 to plate 3 and negative charges from plate 3 to plate 2. This will set up an electric field to counter that from plate 1, so that there will be negligible electric field between plates 2 and 3.

[image]

Comment: pls guide about the charge on plate 1.where would they lie. and also what would be the charge on plate 2 on the side facing plate 1

Comment: Initially, the positive charge on plate 1 would be distributed evenly on the outer surface of the plate. This will induce a negative charge on the surface of plate 2 facing plate 1 and an equal and opposite (positive) charge on the surface of plate 2 facing plate 3. In turn, plate 3 will then have a negative charge on the surface facing plate 2 and an equal and opposite (positive) charge on the surface facing away.